# Apache Math percentile Input data sorted

Tags: java, apache

I am trying to use the Apache Math percentile functionality for records which have more than 1 l lakh data points.

I am currently sorting the input data using Arrays.sort(inputArray).

I was wondering if I can skip this sort step , If the sort has been implemented by the Apache Developers internally.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can, if you overwrite the implementation, with your code. However if you are unsatisfied due to a performance problem I'd like to advise you to update to a newer version if you can. This has been a problem since the 2.0 version and [has now been fixed since version 3.1](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/changes-report.html#a3.1).